# Set IE specific css styles via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to set a CSS property, that is specific to IE, via javascript. Something like the following

```
document.body.style.-ms-content-zooming = "zoom";
```

or

```
document.body.style.-ms-scroll-snap-x = "whatever"
```

But the css property doesn't get set the way shown above (I tried the first line for sure). How could I accomplish the above task, or setting any css starting with a dash (**-**) for that matter, using **javascript**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have an Internet Explorer at hand but usually styles containing dashes are camelcased like:

```
document.body.style.msContentZooming = "zoom";
```

[See this MSDN Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2012/01/11/with-vendor-prefixes-what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-ms.aspx)

Comment: great ..  This actually worked ..! will accept the answer in 6min.

Comment: cool, was'nt sure if MS did it the same way, but I've found a reference that confirms this first hand.

Comment: FYI: the reason for this is that JavaScript treats the `-` character as a `subtract` operation